# Не заходит в метод onRequestPermissionsResult из класса, который используется в Activity (Java)

Tags: java, android-permissions, android-app-compat-activity

Есть у меня SplashActivity. В методе onStart я создаю экземпляр класса ExternalStorage. Данный класс, содержит метод, который вызывает requestPermissions. В том же классе я переопределяю метод onRequestPermissionsResult. Однако, после вызова requestPermissions, программа не заходит в метод onRequestPermissionsResult. При этом, если  делаю вызов requestPermissions напрямую из SplashActivity, то onRequestPermissionsResult работает.
В манифесте указал для SplashActivity:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
```

Вот как выглядит сам код в SplashActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    externalStorage = new ExternalStorage(this, context, getPackageName());
```

Так пишу в самом классе ExternalStorage:

```
  private boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            String[] permissions = new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, 1);
            return false;
        }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    user_define_permission = true;
}
```

Заранее прошу прощения за вопрос, после фортрана тяжело перейти к такому сложному языку.

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult и не должен работать вне активити (фрагмента) не созданного и запущенного системой. Если вы всё таки хотите делать обратоку результата в к-л другом классе - то переопределяйте onRequestPermissionsResult в активити и в нём вызывайте метод своего класса.

Comment: Юрий благодарю за помощь!